# android studio: plugin flutter-i18n does not work

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When i create 'flutter project' in Android Studio with `flutter-i18n` plugin connected there's no `lib/generated/i18n.dart` created. So no working mechanizm for internazionalization as described [in doc](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n).

**my settings are:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /home/valerius/DevTools/Flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/valerius/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/valerius/DevTools/AStudio/182.5264788/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/valerius/DevTools/AStudio/182.5264788
    • Flutter plugin version 33.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
```

---

```
Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
```

Answer (score 6):

Just check if the file: **misc.xml** exists inside of .idea folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ExternalStorageConfigurationManager" enabled="true" />
  <component name="NodePackageJsonFileManager">
    <packageJsonPaths />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
  </component>
</project>
```

> Issue: https://github.com/long1eu/flutter_i18n/issues/37

Comment: Addon to Cristian's answer: not only file `./.idea/misc.xml` - one should add exactly the lines above.

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of Android Studio-3.3.1 bug...
As soon as i downgraded subj to 3.2 all became correct.

Comment: I am using Android Studio - 3.3.2 and it is still the same