# flutter i18n plugin not working in android studio 3.4.0

Tags: android-studio, flutter

flutter i18n plugin not working in android studio 3.4.0
i18n.dart file not generated automatically in Android Studio
version of AS 3.4.0
flutter -version 1.5.4
flutter i18n-version 1.0.2

Comment: You mean flutter i18n for Jetbrains https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n?

Comment: not working in android studio 3.4.0

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861411/android-studio-plugin-flutter-i18n-does-not-work

Comment: i tried that solution but steel not getting i18n.dart file @Joe A

Comment: Have you read through the GitHub to find out more info on it https://github.com/long1eu/flutter_i18n

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use following approach. It's tested with flutter web and mobile

Include this in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  #i18n
  flutter_i18n:

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/i18n/
```

Dummy main page widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
      //i18n stuff
      localizationsDelegates: [
        FlutterI18nDelegate(
          useCountryCode: false,
          fallbackFile: 'en',
          path: 'assets/i18n',
        ),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: new LoginPage(),
    );
  }
```

Put this in assets/i18n/en.json

```
{
  "login_screen": {
    "button": {
      "login": "LOGIN"
    }
  }
}
```

Now use these strings as following:

```
Text(FlutterI18n.translate(
    context, 'login_screen.button.login'))
```

Comment: This is not the answer to question.